# Continue training after keyboard interrupt?

Tags: tensorflow

I was training tensorflow and then i mashed the keyboard for shits and giggles:

```
INFO:tensorflow:global step 101: loss = 5.1761 (52.61 sec/step)
INFO:tensorflow:global step 102: loss = 4.8679 (18.78 sec/step)
INFO:tensorflow:global step 103: loss = 4.9662 (19.02 sec/step)
INFO:tensorflow:global step 104: loss = 5.1126 (17.36 sec/step)
^C^X^C^[^[^[^[^[





exit
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/kristoffer/web/im2txt/im2txt/bazel-bin/im2txt/train.runfiles/im2txt/im2txt/train.py", line 114, in <module>
    tf.app.run()
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/platform/app.py", line 43, in run
    sys.exit(main(sys.argv[:1] + flags_passthrough))
  File "/Users/kristoffer/web/im2txt/im2txt/bazel-bin/im2txt/train.runfiles/im2txt/im2txt/train.py", line 110, in main
    saver=saver)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/contrib/slim/python/slim/learning.py", line 782, in train
    sess, train_op, global_step, train_step_kwargs)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/contrib/slim/python/slim/learning.py", line 530, in train_step
    run_metadata=run_metadata)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 766, in run
    run_metadata_ptr)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 964, in _run
    feed_dict_string, options, run_metadata)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1014, in _do_run
    target_list, options, run_metadata)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1021, in _do_call
    return fn(*args)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1003, in _run_fn
    status, run_metadata)
KeyboardInterrupt
Kristoffers-MacBook-Pro:im2txt kristoffer$ logout
Saving session...
...copying shared history...
...saving history...truncating history files...
...completed.

[Process completed]
```

When I'm trying to start training again, I get the following error:

```
$ bazel-bin/im2txt/train   --input_file_pattern="${MSCOCO_DIR}/train-?????-of-00256"   --inception_checkpoint_file="${INCEPTION_CHECKPOINT}"   --train_dir="${MODEL_DIR}/train"   --train_inception=false   --number_of_steps=150
CRITICAL:tensorflow:Found no input files matching /train-?????-of-00256
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/kristoffer/web/im2txt/im2txt/bazel-bin/im2txt/train.runfiles/im2txt/im2txt/train.py", line 114, in <module>
    tf.app.run()
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/platform/app.py", line 43, in run
    sys.exit(main(sys.argv[:1] + flags_passthrough))
  File "/Users/kristoffer/web/im2txt/im2txt/bazel-bin/im2txt/train.runfiles/im2txt/im2txt/train.py", line 65, in main
    model.build()
  File "/Users/kristoffer/web/im2txt/im2txt/bazel-bin/im2txt/train.runfiles/im2txt/im2txt/show_and_tell_model.py", line 353, in build
    self.build_inputs()
  File "/Users/kristoffer/web/im2txt/im2txt/bazel-bin/im2txt/train.runfiles/im2txt/im2txt/show_and_tell_model.py", line 153, in build_inputs
    num_reader_threads=self.config.num_input_reader_threads)
  File "/Users/kristoffer/web/im2txt/im2txt/bazel-bin/im2txt/train.runfiles/im2txt/im2txt/ops/inputs.py", line 98, in prefetch_input_data
    data_files, shuffle=True, capacity=16, name=shard_queue_name)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/training/input.py", line 211, in string_input_producer
    raise ValueError(not_null_err)
ValueError: string_input_producer requires a non-null input tensor
```

What causes this and what can I do about it? Is there a proper way to pause/cancel a training session? (Tensorflow seems to pick up where it left of if you startup with training 50 steps and then set the steps to 100)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like your problem is caused by that `Tensorflow` is trying to load a session, which wasn't properly saved when you interrupted your code. Your solutions now would either be not loading the last session when you restart the code (by commenting the loading line), or deleting the saved session files (then it should automatically restart from scratch). It is hard to give a more specific example, since you didn't share your code...